# Equivalence of seminorms of Schwartz space

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I have seen the definitions of the family of seminorms defined on Schwartz spaces vary slightly in literature. For example the following

$$\rho_{a,b}(f) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}|x^aD^bf(x)|,$$

$$\hat{\rho_{a,b}}(f) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}|x|^{|a|}|D^bf(x)|$$

and

$$\tilde{\rho_{a,b}}(f) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}(1+|x|)^{|a|}|D^bf(x)|,$$

where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $a$ is multiindex.

How can I show the equivalence of these definitions?

---

And another question would be whether we have

$$\sup_{a,b\in\mathbb{N}}\rho_{a,b}(f)=M<\infty$$

for $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For equivalence between $\rho$ and $\widehat\rho$, use the fact that the Euclidian norm and $\lVert x\rVert_{\infty}:=\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}|x_j|$ are equivalent.

For $\widetilde \rho$, "cut the $\sup$" into two parts: $|x|\leqslant 1$ and $|x|>1$.

The supremum you mentionned is not finite unless $f=0$. Indeed, we get $f(x)=0$ when $|x|>1$, and on $[-1,1]$ the sequence $(f^{(k)},k\geqslant 0)$ is uniformly bounded. Using fundamental theorem of analysis, we find $f=0$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have updated a little bit of the current question. Would you mind read it again?

Comment: @newbie I've edited accordingly.